# Discord - get - How to read direct messages of an user using API

Tags: api, discord, message

1. What is the discord API to read all direct messages for an user
2. What Discord API we can use to read all channels/threads that user is having access to

Comment: (a) Have you checked the documentation? These both look like pretty easy things to look up? (b) [Please ask only one question at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627).

Comment: yes, from discord https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/application
There are APIs to read channel, but i coudnt see any api to read direct messages